# Context menu not loading in SherlockActivity

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm working on an application. In an activity, the activity list the content from server and display it in a list view. I'm extending SherlockActivity. But the context menu is not appearing. the code goes like this

NewsActivity.java

```
package com.ministry.ensing119app.news;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.ministry.ensing119app.Contact;
import com.ministry.ensing119app.HomeScreen;
import com.ministry.ensing119app.R;
import com.ministry.ensing119app.bible.BibleActivity;
import com.ministry.ensing119app.donate.Donate;
import com.ministry.ensing119app.photos.GetPath;
import com.ministry.ensing119app.sermonnotes.Notes_list;

public class NewsActivity extends SherlockActivity {

public static String url = "http://ensignweb.com/sandbox/app/comment11.php";

    // JSON Node names
    protected static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    protected static final String TAG_CID = "cid";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // contacts JSONArray  
    JSONArray products = null;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
            Log.d("if condition", "if condition is running");
            new Message().execute(url);


//           The service section
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,UpdateService.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000, pIntent);
            startService(new Intent(this, UpdateService.class));
        } else {
            Log.d("if condition", "else condition is running");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is no internet or low. Please check", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(returnIntent);
        }        
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.news, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.donate:
            Intent newsIntent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Donate.class);
            startActivity(newsIntent);
            break;

        case R.id.photos:
            Intent photoIntent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, GetPath.class);
            startActivity(photoIntent);
            break;

        case R.id.notepad:
            Intent notePadIntent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Notes_list.class);
            startActivity(notePadIntent);
            break;

        case R.id.contact:
            Intent contactIntent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this,Contact.class);
            startActivity(contactIntent);
            break;

        case R.id.bible:
            Intent BibleIntent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, BibleActivity.class);
            startActivity(BibleIntent);
            break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    class Message extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> > {

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this);
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                @Override
            protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {

                    Log.d("doInBackgound","backgound is running");

                    // getting JSON string from URL
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                    Log.d("path_parsing", "before parsing");
                    try {
                        // Getting Array of Contacts
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for(int i = products.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String cid = c.getString(TAG_CID).toString();
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_CID, cid);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            mylist.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("path_parsing", "after parsing");
                    return mylist;

                }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
                if(progress.isShowing()){
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(NewsActivity.this, result , R.layout.list_item,new String[] { TAG_NAME,}, new int[] {
                        R.id.name});
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                Log.d("postExecute","Postexecute is running");

            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                progress.setTitle("Progress");
                progress.setMessage("Please have patience");
                progress.show();
            }
      }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Share");
    }


}
```

Please help me on this. I'm newbie to android.

Comment: Change `MenuItem` with `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem` of `onMenuItemSelected()`

Answer (score 0):

In your `menu.xml` items should have set `showAsAction` property if you want them in actionbar. Note that if you have too many items, not all will be visible. Those ones which are not visible are in the overflow menu or in the menu under physical menu button in your phone.

Answer (score 0):

you have't used this in your code: `registerForContextMenu(yourView);`

here is [simple example](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/) how to use `ContextMenu` in android.